# Spring RestTemplate with site Setlist.fm

Tags: android, spring, rest, curl, resttemplate

I have a curl string such as:

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' --header 'x-api-key: KEY' 'https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/search/setlists?artistName=Springsteen&date=03-07-2016&p=1'

Request url is: https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/search/setlists?artistName=Springsteen&date=03-07-2016&p=1

Which is ths correct java working code in Android ?
I have

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
requestBody.put("artistName", "Springsteen");
requestBody.put("date", "" + dataConcerto);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("x-api-key", "key");

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody.toString(), headers);

String response = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/search/setlists", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class).getBody();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is the requestBody.toString(). You have to add the params as query string params. E.g.

```
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("x-api-key", "yourkey");

final UriComponentsBuilder b = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/search/setlists");
b.queryParam("artistName", "Springsteen");

final String response = restTemplate.exchange(b.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class).getBody();
System.out.println(response);
```